# How to do '101,102,103' to '101','102','103' in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a string inside a stored procedure, I store some data just like

```
string pkid = '101,102,103'
```

I want to convert that to

```
pkid = '101', '102', '103'
```

How do I do that?

Comment: copy the string to excel, use data text to columns, then transpose, then create the desired output and copy paste back to sp.

Comment: This is not a SQL question (neither line of code is valid SQL).  Please tag it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will replace all the commas with ','  and adds a ' at the beginning and end.

```
declare @pkid varchar(100);
set @pkid = '101,102,103';
set @pkid = ''''+replace (@pkid,',',''',''')+'''';
select @pkid as pkid
```

**OUTPUT**

```
pkid
'101','102','103'
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".